# ORACLE - select data from VARRAY OF REF Object

Tags: sql, oracle, ref, varray

I am using ORACLE and want to access an Object of an array with REF. This is my Structure:

```
create type articulo as object (
    codigo_barras number,
    nombre varchar2(100),
    precio number,
    categoria varchar2(100),
    stock number
                               );

create table almacen of articulo(
    codigo_barras primary key
    );

create table estanteria(
    identificador varchar2(10) primary key ,
    pasillo number,
    seccion character,
    producto ref articulo scope is almacen
);

create type lista as VARRAY(5) of REF articulo;

create table escaparate(
  tablon number primary key ,
  lista_productos lista
);

insert into almacen values (1,'Destornillador',5,'Herramientas',20);
insert into almacen values (2,'Llave inglesa',12,'Herramientas',30);
insert into almacen values (3,'Martillo',16,'Herramientas',20);
insert into almacen values (4,'Soplete',24,'Maquinaria',5);
insert into almacen values (5,'Radial',35,'Maquinaria',10);

insert into estanteria
select 1,1,'A',ref(a)
from almacen a
where a.CODIGO_BARRAS=1;

insert into estanteria
select 2,3,'B',ref(a)
from almacen a
where a.CODIGO_BARRAS=4;

insert into escaparate
select 1,lista(REF(a1),REF(a2))
FROM almacen a1, almacen a2
where a1.CODIGO_BARRAS=1 and a2.CODIGO_BARRAS=2;
```

The problem i s when i try to access escaparate, can't reach data from the VARRAY of REFS.  Tried this:

```
select e.tablon, t.nombre
from escaparate e, table( e.lista_productos ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A table collection expression returns the data with the `COLUMN_VALUE` identifier, you can use this to get the `REF` value:

```sql
SELECT e.tablon,
       t.COLUMN_VALUE.nombre AS nombre
FROM   escaparate e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table( e.lista_productos ) t
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

*(You can also `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that you will get rows if the `VARRAY` is empty or `NULL`.)*

So, for the data:

```sql
insert into escaparate ( tablon, lista_productos )
VALUES (
  1,
  lista(
    ( SELECT REF(a) FROM almacen a WHERE CODIGO_BARRAS=1 ),
    ( SELECT REF(a) FROM almacen a WHERE CODIGO_BARRAS=2 )
  )
);

insert into escaparate ( tablon, lista_productos )
VALUES ( 2,lista() );

insert into escaparate ( tablon, lista_productos )
VALUES ( 3, NULL );
```

This outputs:

> ```
> TABLON | NOMBRE        
> -----: | :-------------
>      1 | Destornillador
>      1 | Llave inglesa 
>      2 | null          
>      3 | null
> ```

Or, if you want the position in the array, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT e.tablon,
       t.*
FROM   escaparate e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                t.COLUMN_VALUE.nombre AS nombre
         FROM   TABLE( e.lista_productos ) t
       ) t
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> TABLON |   RN | NOMBRE        
> -----: | ---: | :-------------
>      1 |    1 | Destornillador
>      1 |    2 | Llave inglesa 
>      2 | null | null          
>      3 | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7916d4ab775de33595e62bf89c38bf36)*

Comment: You can simplify the last example, by using `OUTER APPLY` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL` - that way you won't need the redundant `ON` condition.